# Why don't alcohols undergo nucleophilic substitution with ammonia?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

Alcohols can undergo nucleophilic substitution with $\ce{PCl5, POCl3, HCl}$.  Halogenoalkanes can undergo nucleophilic substitution with $\ce{NH3}$. The $\ce{C-O}$ (in alcohol) and $\ce{C-Cl}$ (in chloroalkanes) bond energies are comparable. Why don't alcohols undergo nucleophilic substitution with $\ce{NH3}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build on ssavec's answer: [Nucleophilic substitution reactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleophilic_substitution) require two species: a [nucleophile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleophile) (a Lewis Base) and a substrate with a [leaving group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleophile). Nucleophiles are often generically represented as $\ce{Nu}$ and leavings groups as $\ce{LG}$.

All leaving groups are not created equal. The leaving group ability of a leaving group is defined as the relative rates of a particular analogous series of substitutions. For example, the relative leaving group ability might be based on the following reaction, with rates determined for various leaving groups:

$$\ce{EtOH + PhCH(LG)CH3 -> PhCH(OEt)CH3 + H-LG}$$

This is an [$\mathrm{S_N1}$ substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sn1), so the first (and rate determining) step of the mechanism is loss of the leaving group (and is independent of the nucleophile):

$$\ce{PhCH(LG)CH3 -> PhCH+CH3 + LG-}$$

The relative rates of this reaction are influenced by the stability of the $\ce{LG-}$ anion (see the [Hammond Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammond_postulate), which proposes that the transition state of an endothermic process resembles the products).

The stability of the $\ce{LG-}$ anion can be predicted from the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of the conjugate acid of $\ce{LG-}$, which is controlled by the same ability to stabilize a negative charge.

The conjugate acid of $\ce{Cl-}$ is $\ce{HCl}$, which is a strong acid. Using some Hess's Law trickery, the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{HCl}$ has been predicted to be around $-8$.

The conjugate acid of $\ce{OH-}$ is $\ce{H2O}$, which has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ around $+16$.

$\ce{H2O}$ is a much weaker acid than $\ce{HCl}$, which means that the negative charge on  $\ce{OH-}$ is less stabilized than $\ce{Cl-}$. Thus, $\ce{OH-}$ is a poorer leaving group than $\ce{Cl-}$ (by a lot).

Another good discussion of leaving groups (and the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ data used above) [come from this site](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/04/12/what-makes-a-good-leaving-group/).

In your example reaction (ammonia + ethanol), the product of the reaction has a better leaving group ($\ce{NH3}$, conjugate base of $\ce{NH4+}$, which has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $+9.75$) than the $\ce{OH-}$ leaving group in the reactant, so the reaction will also run in reverse, and the equilibrium will strongly favor the reactants.

$$\ce{CH3CH2OH + NH3 <=> CH3CH2}\color{red}{\ce{NH3+}}\ce{+ OH-}\ \ K_\mathrm{a} \ll 1$$

As for your confusion about bond energies...

Bond dissociation energies are defined for [homolytic bond cleavage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homolysis_%28chemistry%29), in which each atom keeps one electron when the bond breaks (see image).

[image: homolysis]

Substitution reactions involve [heterolytic bond cleavage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterolysis_%28chemistry%29), in which one atom gets both electrons:

[image: heterolysis]

Comment: Nevertheless the question is wrong basicly, because amines are produced from alcoholes and ammonia at multi-thousands of tonnes each year. This is just a question of conditions. Under high enough temperature and pressure (about ammonia synthesis conditions and catalysts) the reaction takes place.

Comment: Oh, well, sure. Catalysts change the **mechanisms** of reactions, so what was once slow/nonproductive starts to become productive. This question appeared to be at the introductory organic level, and I kept my answer there also.

Answer (score 5):

The $\ce{OH-}$ is a very poor leaving group, however, $\ce{H2O}$ is a very good leaving group. Of course, one only needs to acidify to convert one group to the other. For chloride as the nucleophile, this poses no problems; $\ce{HCl}$ is a strong acid and $\ce{Cl-}$ is a weak conjugate base. However, ammonia is a pretty good base, and it converts to the ammonium ion $\ce{NH4+}$ at acidic pH. This greatly reduces its capability as a nucleophile, and the reaction does not proceed.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I couldn't mark both as the answer. For the benefit of future viewers of this page, this answer is also brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

In substitution, you must think not only about nucleophile, but also about leaving group. That means, alcohols react only with very good nucleophiles, because $\rm{OH^-}$ is so bad leaving group.

Comment: Could you tell me why $\ce{Cl}$ in $\ce{PCl5}$, etc. is a better nucleophile than $\ce{NH3}$ then?

Comment: @user2246 PCl5first converts OH into OPCl4 and in succesive intramolecular substitution POCl3 acts as very good leaving group.

Answer (score -4):

Simply because ammonia is a great base(due to the presence of 2 lone pairs) and hence the basic character always dominates over the nucleophilic character.

Comment: 1. Ammonia isn't a great base 2. Ammonia doesn't have two lone pairs 3. There are a ton of reactions where ammonia preferentially reacts as a nucleophile rather than as a base. In conclusion, literally everything you've said is wrong.